# Send allure report results to aws s3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, rspec, allure

Currently I am using Ruby, Appium and Allure to generate my reports (allure-rspec). My tests are running on continuous integration (BuddyBuild) and I have a bucket on aws s3. 
After generating the report structure with all the necessary files, I can see the report just generating a server locally, but I would like to send the html file to my bucket in s3.
After generating the report with the results of my test, I already tried to send all the allure files to my bucket, but unfortunately the report is only generated after using the `allure open` or `allure serve` commands. How can I send the results to my bucket to share the results with my team?

Comment: Looking for the same answer, found just this: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/755
They propose: 
1) Enable the web-hosting feature of your s3 bucket 
2) Generate report: "allure generate -c reports/allure-results -o reports/allure-results-html"
3) Upload report to s3: "aws s3 sync reports/allure-results-html s3://your_bucket/"

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi Yes, actually this is my solution that I posted there :) Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my solution to upload the report to AWS S3

## Generate Allure report

```
allure generate -c reports/allure-results -o reports/allure-results-html
```

## Upload HTML report to AWS S3

```
aws s3 sync reports/allure-results-html s3://your_bucket/
```